# Nothing downloads on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore

So, I'm an iPhone 5c user, who was on iOS 8 for quite a while. I recently was convinced to update to the newest update (which I believe is 10.3.3), and ever since then, my phone has been bedeviled with issues.

It started with my phone constantly deleting my tabs after leaving Safari, then the Camera Roll being wiped (the photos eventually got restored, but this keeps happening multiple times), as well as my music, podcasts, and contacts being deleted off my phone.

The most recent issue, and the main one I'm asking about, is that my phone is absolutely refusing to download anything, which includes the previously-mentioned podcasts and music, but mainly any apps or updates. If I try, after a short while, an error message will come up saying 'Unable to Download'.

I've done a lot of research, and tried basically everything recommended, including:

- restarting the phone
- force rebooting the phone
- force closing the App Store itself
- signing in and out of my Apple ID
- clearing-the-cache thing on the App Store

None of these actions fix the problem. Any suggestions on how else I can try to resolve this?

Comment: i suppose you still have memory room on your phone.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best course of action would be to commit to a factory reset ***after backing up your data***.

According to this [support doc](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201252) you can do so by plugging your device into a machine with iTunes installed, unlocking the device if it has a passcode and then clicking on it in iTunes.

In the device summary there should be a button that reads "Restore iPhone..." or something of the like. Click on that and then click Restore on the resulting new window to confirm your decision.

Your device will then be erased and re-installed with a brand new factory image corresponding to the latest version of iOS available for your device.

Comment: If you could please summarize the steps found in the link. We don't want this site to be come a farm of broken links so at least summarizing the steps helps a lot.

Comment: @SteveChambers done :) I think this is much more qualitative in terms of a response. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Excellent, don't forget to back up the phone first!